# How can I prove that I designed the site?

Tags: internet

I have designed a website for a client,
But there is no contract between us.

The client does not pay my salary,
But our text and voice messages are available.

How can I prove that I designed the site and complain about him?

Comment: Which country are you in, and where is your client? Details differ.

Comment: What do the text and voice messages say? If you have messages in which you agree to design a website and then messages where you say you've created the site and the client acknowledges the existence of the site, then that would probably be proof. But it will depend on the precise contents of the messages.

Answer (score 4):

By "complain" I assume you mean "take legal action against him". You would need a legal basis, and a lawyer. When you say that you don't have a contract, I assume you mean that you don't have a piece of signed paper, but you do have an agreement – which *is* a contract. As far as websites are concerned, there are only a few likely causes of legal action: copyright infringement, and non-payment for services. As far as copyright is concerned, [this law](https://web.archive.org/web/20110505081941/http://softreg.ir/rules/copyright.html) may be relevant. If we assume that you and the client are operating in Iran, your copyright is protected, but Iran does not enforce other country's copyright laws (they are not signatories to the Berne Convention).

If the issue is that the client is not paying for services rendered, you can sue them. The civil code (in English) is [here](https://www.refworld.org/pdfid/49997adb27.pdf). See article 219 ff. for the specifics, but basically you show the judge that there is an agreement, and that you were not paid. The client can then argue that you didn't actually do the job agreed to, or that you were paid. There are other possible responses (e.g. the "client" might prove that you agreed to do the work for free), the details of which will come out in your discussion with the lawyer.